# java mvc authorization without spring security

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My task is to use a send request and then to get some XML.

example: 
request: /api/ext/data.xml 
response: some XML

The application uses Spring MVC, so I just wrote controller method, and everything works OK, but I also need to implement authorization. This app does not use Spring security.

What should I do? Should I use session to save User authorization data?

Comment: If authorization and authentication is required I recommend using spring-security. I'm fairly sure it will be a better solution then what you might implement yourself.

Comment: It depends of how complicated security model you need. Sometimes Basic Auth in Tomcat + https will be enough, sometimes you have to use spring-security or shiro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should still look at Apache Shiro and/or Spring Security. However Spring Security (and container security for that matter) are not so friendly for REST API security. For Spring you will need to implement a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to avoid the redirect on `403`. Shiro might be a little easier for REST API.

If you want to do it yourself w/o dependencies or complexities you should look into writing a [Servlet Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and/or leverage container security. A compromise might be this [SecurityFilter project](http://securityfilter.sourceforge.net/). However if you need Roles, ACLs etc... you should seriously reconsider Shiro or Spring Security.

Answer (score 0):

And what about implementing your own HmacSha1 model (signed requests) as Amazon Web Services do?

Basics: Client signs the request with a Secret access key (SAK) and expire data, obtaining an hmac code. 
Then client sends via POST the request plus some headers like hmac code and expire data and whatever you need. The server then gets your request in the controller (or interceptor), signs it with your SAK and expire time, and compares obtaining hmacs to validate user.